# Why does sbt run throw Overlapping output directories with Slick's code generator?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, slick

I'm trying to migrate [the computer-database example from Play 2.3](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.3.x/samples/scala/computer-database) from `anorm` to Slick 2. I want to use [Slick's code generator](https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-example).

This is my `project/build.scala`

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object build extends Build {

  lazy val mainProject = Project(
    id = "main",
    base = file("."),
    settings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ Seq(
      scalaVersion := "2.10.4",
      libraryDependencies ++= List(
        "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.2",
        "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
        "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.170"
      ),
      // register manual sbt command
      slick <<= slickCodeGenTask,
      // register automatic code generation on every compile, remove for only manual use
      sourceGenerators in Compile <+= slickCodeGenTask
    )
  )

  // Slick's code generation task
  lazy val slick = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("gen-tables")

  lazy val slickCodeGenTask = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (dir, cp, r, s) =>
    // place generated files in sbt's managed sources folder
    val outputDir = (dir / "slick").getPath
    // connection info for a pre-populated throw-away, in-memory db for this demo, which is freshly initialized on every run
    val url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=runscript from 'conf/sql/create.sql'"
    val jdbcDriver = "org.h2.Driver"
    val slickDriver = "scala.slick.driver.H2Driver"
    val pkg = "demo"
    toError(r.run("scala.slick.model.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator", cp.files, Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg), s.log))
    val fname = outputDir + "/demo/Tables.scala"
    Seq(file(fname))
  }
}
```

When I try to run my application with `sbt run` I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Overlapping output directories:/home/myuser/computer-database/target:
    ProjectRef(file:/home/myuser/computer-database/,main)
    ProjectRef(file:/home/myuser/computer-database/,root)
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.Predef$.error(Predef.scala:142)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(Load.scala:140)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(Load.scala:140)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:140)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:37)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:473)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:467)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:467)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:95)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:179)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:93)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:66)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:66)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:49)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:33)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:25)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:57)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] Overlapping output directories:/home/myuser/computer-database/target:
[error]     ProjectRef(file:/home/myuser/computer-database/,main)
[error]     ProjectRef(file:/home/myuser/computer-database/,root)
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

If I change `id = "main"` into `id = "root"` the previous error is not triggered anymore, but a new one instead:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 08-Jun-2014 20:22:41
```

There seems to be a problem with Project ID (whatever that is). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to remove `root` declaration from `build.sbt` and enable `PlayScala` plugin in `Build.scala`.

`build.sbt`

```
name := "computer-database"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.2",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.7.0-M1"
)

scalaVersion := Option(System.getProperty("scala.version")).getOrElse("2.10.4")
```

`project/Build.scala`

```
import play.PlayScala
import sbt._
import Keys._


object myBuild extends Build {

    lazy val mainProject = Project(
        id = "main",
        base = file("."),
        settings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ Seq(
            scalaVersion := "2.10.4",
            libraryDependencies ++= List(
                "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.2",
                "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
                "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.170"
            ),
            slick <<= slickCodeGenTask, // register manual sbt command
            sourceGenerators in Compile <+= slickCodeGenTask // register automatic code generation on every compile, remove for only manual use
        )
    ).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

    // code generation task
    lazy val slick = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("gen-tables")

    lazy val slickCodeGenTask = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (dir, cp, r, s) =>
        val outputDir = (dir / "slick").getPath // place generated files in sbt's managed sources folder
        val url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=runscript from 'conf/sql/create.sql'" // connection info for a pre-populated throw-away, in-memory db for this demo, which is freshly initialized on every run
        val jdbcDriver = "org.h2.Driver"
        val slickDriver = "scala.slick.driver.H2Driver"
        val pkg = "demo"
        toError(r.run("scala.slick.model.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator", cp.files, Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg), s.log))
        val fname = outputDir + "/demo/Tables.scala"
        Seq(file(fname))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you also have a build.sbt file in the root directory? Such as here https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/samples/scala/computer-database/build.sbt. That would explain overlapping output directories error. Delete the project root defined in build.sbt, so project in Build.scala is used.

Next, my guess changing id from "main" to "root" in the second part gives the new error, is because you have a play project but "mainProject" defined in Build.scala doesn't have Play plugin so `run` behaves differently.

Comment: Yes I do have the same build.sbt, but removing `root` from it doesn't change anything, still exactly the same error.

Comment: `clean` then `run`? The same location File(".") should not have project created in multiple places (build.sbt, Build.scala)

Comment: Yes, `clean` and `run`, no change.

Comment: not sure what the problem is. If you removed project `root` defined in `build.sbt`, then you shouldn't get this line in the stack trace anymore: `ProjectRef(file:/home/myuser/computer-database/,root)`. Final thing you could do if you're in a git repo, is git clean -dxf, then try `sbt run`

Comment: I've been reading sbt docs (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html) and if I understand it correctly, my Build.scala file is wrong for Play 2.3 / SBT 0.13.5. This would work on Play 2.2 though. I just don't have any example of Build.scala under Play 2.3

Comment: So you have fixed the first problem with overlapping output directories? Well adding the play 2.3 plugin is another problem. If you already have 2.2, follow the steps here. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23

Answer (score 2):

It is better to load these settings from config:

app/db.conf

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=runscript from 'db.sql'"
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password=""
db.slick.driver = "scala.slick.driver.H2Driver"

# From root
db.model.package = "models"
db.model.outputDir = "app" # not include package
db.model.outputFile = "Tables.scala"
```

build.sbt

```
object myBuild extends Build {
  lazy val slick = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("gen-tables")

  lazy val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("./conf/db.conf"))

  lazy val slickCodeGenTask = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (dir, cp, r, s) =>

    val outputDir = config.getString("db.model.outputDir") // place generated files in sbt's managed sources folder
    val url = config.getString("db.default.url")
    val jdbcDriver = config.getString("db.default.driver")
    val slickDriver = config.getString("db.slick.driver")
    val pkg = config.getString("db.model.package")
    toError(r.run("scala.slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator", cp.files, Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg), s.log))
    val fname = outputDir + config.getString("db.model.outputFile")
    Seq(file(fname))
  }

  lazy val mainProject = Project(
    id="main",
    base=file("."),
    settings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ Seq(
      slick <<= slickCodeGenTask
      // sourceGenerators in Compile <+= slickCodeGenTask
    )).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
}
```